# Real world problems with placing the HTTP Connection: Header at the end

Tags: http-headers, httpconnection, transparentproxy

Are there any known problems with putting the HTTP Connection: field at the end of the headers?

**From the Standard ([RFC2616, section 4.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html)):**

> it is "good practice" to send **general-header fields** first (**which includes `Connection`**), followed by request-header or response-header fields, and ending with the entity-header fields.

Am I gonna get bit if I violate the "good practice" for the `Connection` HTTP Header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is "good practice" only, not a requirement. HTTP implementations are required to support headers appearing in any order.

Comment: Then why is it good practice, if there exist no broken implementations?

Comment: Such "broken implementations" have not really existed anymore for a LONG time.  Here is an interesting perspective on the issue: http://mark.stosberg.com/blog/2010/01/generating-http-headers-sorted-or-unsorted.html